# Problem in Adding line feature in Openlayers vector layer

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, boundless-suite

I have added the WMS line feature in vector layer. But I am facing some display problem in it as shown below screenshot.Is there anyother way to do this?

[image]

But there is no issue in point features.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 selectionLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", { styleMap:
            new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"]),
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
    isBaseLayer: false
});

osMap.addLayers([selectionLayer]);

var wmsFeatInfo = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
url: 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/geoserver/cite/wms',
    title: 'identify features on click',        
    queryVisible: true
});
wmsFeatInfo.infoFormat = 'application/vnd.ogc.gml';
wmsFeatInfo.events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, getWmsFeatAttributes);
osMap.addControl(wmsFeatInfo);
wmsFeatInfo.activate();

function getWmsFeatAttributes(e) {
    selectFeatLst = {};
    if (e.features.length > 0) {       
        for (var ii = 0; ii < e.features.length; ii++) {            
           var layer_ID = e.features[ii].fid.split('.');            
           var featId = layer_ID[1];            
           selectFeatLst[featId] = e.features[ii];
        }        
    }
 }

 function test(key){ 
    selectionLayer.addFeatures([selectFeatLst[key]]); //Here line feature is adding 
 }
```

Please suggest me to fix this issue.

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Please see the first screenshot. Its highlighting somewhere instead of that line

Comment: @venkat: It is not clear what you are trying to show, by using the Image.

Comment: Blue color is the selection color. It should select the line from 'start' to 'end'. But the selection appear somewhere else

Comment: Can you please show the code or values ect where you add the feature to the selectionLayer OpenLayers.Layer.Vector layer. The way you have the code setup here seems to indicate that everything in that layer would display as though selected. In the top picture the lines that appear to have been added(and aren't in the bottom picture) appear to be highlighted as though they are selected. The line that you indicate in the top picture that you want highlighted appears in the bottom picture as well.

Comment: @Darkcylde I have added line,polygon and point features in the selection layer like this selectionLayer.addFeatures([selectFeatLst[key]]); In this selectFeatLst[key] dictionary refers e.features[ii]. Yes I want highlight the WMS features, So the features simply added into selection layer which has the styleMap 'select'.